# I'm trying to use the json file, but it can't be return data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm ganna use this json
but i got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'aFeeds' of undefined
How can I get the value?

```
  return  fetch('https://freemusicarchive.org/featured.json'
    )
        .then(respone => respone.json())
       .then(json => console.log(json))
        .then(json=> json.aFeeds.aTracks)
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in your second `then`, you don't return anything because `console.log` doesn't have a return value. If you want to log it, you'd have to use a function body and `return` the `json`:

```
return fetch("https://freemusicarchive.org/featured.json")
    .then(respone => respone.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        return json;
    })
    .then(json => json.aFeeds.aTracks)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```